almost single-valued upper hemicontinuous function
Let $f$ be a set-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.
It satisfies the following conditions:
(1) For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(t)$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$;
(2) $f(q)$ is a singleton for any rational number $q$;
(3) For any rational number $q$ and any sequence of rational numbers $\{q_n\}$ with $q_n$ converging to $q$ as $n$ tends to infinity, $f(q_n) \to f(q)$ as $n\to \infty$;
(4) $f$ is an upper hemicontinuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, that is, for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and any open set $V$ with $f(t)\subset V$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $t$ (the diameter of $U$ depends on $t'$) such that $f(t')\subset V$ for any $t'\in U$.
Given the conditions outlined above, can we conclude that for any rational number $q$, there exists a radius $r>0$ (which may depend on $q$) such that $f$ is single-valued and continuous on the interval $(q-r,q+r)$?

Show your attempts please, by editing your question.

No, it is not necessarily the case that such $f$ is locally single-valued at each rational number. To produce a counter example, find any enumeration $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the rational numbers, then define the function $H(x)=\inf\{2^n\cdot|x-q_n| : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and finally define the set-valued function $f(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R} : |y|\leq H(x)\}$. We shall prove that $f$ satisfies your criteria, but fails to be single-valued on any open interval.
Firstly, it's obvious that $f(x)$ is always a closed interval (or a singleton, when $H(x)=0$), hence we always have $f(x)$ being a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. This verifies condition (1).
Next, each rational $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ must admit $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $x=q_n$, and then $H(x)\leq 2^n\cdot|x-q_n| = 0$ so that $H(x)=0$. This proves that $f(x)=\{0\}$ for any rational $x$, so condition (2) is also satisfied.
Verifying condition (3) is straightforward, as we actually have that $H$ is continuous at all rational numbers. Indeed, given $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, we find $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $q=q_k$, and then as we limit $t\to q_k$ we'll see $H(t)\leq 2^k\cdot |t-q_k|$ and thus $H(t)\to 0$. This easily implies $\lim_{t\to q} f(t) = f(q)$.
Verifying condition (4) is similar, though somewhat harder. We'll show that for any fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $\limsup_{t\to x} H(t) \leq H(x)$. To prove this, first notice that for any $y>H(x)$, by definition of $H$ there must exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $y>2^n\cdot |x-q_n|$. Consequently, as $t\to x$ we have $H(t)\leq 2^n\cdot |t-q_n| \to 2^n\cdot|x-q_n| < y$, hence $\limsup_{t\to x} H(t) \leq y$. Since this holds for all $y>H(x)$, we easily infer $\limsup_{t\to x} H(t) \leq H(x)$. I leave it to you to verify that this implies your condition (4).
Finally, we need to prove that our $f$ is actually a counter example. For each $\epsilon>0$, consider the set $S_\epsilon=\{x\in\mathbb{R} : H(x)<\epsilon\}$, then we easily put a bound on the Lebesgue measure $\lambda(S_\epsilon)\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \lambda(\{x\in\mathbb{R} : 2^n\cdot |x-q_n|<\epsilon\}) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \epsilon\cdot 2^{1-n} = 4\epsilon$. Due to continuity of measure, we have a sort of limit $\lambda(\{x\in\mathbb{R} : H(x)=0\}) = \lambda(\bigcap_{\epsilon>0} S_\epsilon) \leq \inf_{\epsilon>0} \lambda(S_\epsilon) = 0$. Therefore, we have that $H$ is nonzero almost everywhere, and so there cannot exist any open interval on which $H$ is constantly zero. We easily see that $f$ is nonsingular anywhere that $H$ is nonzero, and moreover $f$ is discontinuous anywhere that $H$ is nonzero. Therefore, $f$ is both nonsingular and discontinuous almost everywhere. More relevantly, there cannot exist any open interval on which $f$ is singular and continuous.

The function $H$ is
(a) continuous at any rational number $q$ and $H(q)=0$;
(b) upper semicontinuous; and
(c) nonzero almost everywhere.
This function is very interesting and thought-provoking. Thanks!
